# initOwner role - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am wondering why there is a need to `initOwner()` while creating a Alert? The both codes - with and without `initOwner()` work. Could anyone tell me why I should use the `initOwner()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the different look and behavior as pointed out by Jan's answer, the window ownership hierarchy effects [window modality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html#WINDOW_MODAL).

For a window modal dialog, if you set an owner, the dialog will block input for the owner stage and the user won't be able to close the owner stage without first closing the child.

If you have a window modal dialog with an owner, the user won't be able to focus on a field in the owner dialog until the child dialog is closed.

If the window modal dialog has no owner, the user can switch focus between a field in the owner and the child.

For non-modal windows with an owner, ownership also effects closure of windows.  If the user closes the parent window, the child will also close.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the OS, the dialog might be displayed differently depending on whether or not it has an owner. If you look at the OS X example of a file open dialog in the picture below, the dialog is "slided out" of the owner windows top if specified. If there is no owner window specified, the dialog will be displayed as a regular "detached" dialog window.

[image]